# Replace value from 1 worksheet to another using a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need a way to replace values in my primary worksheet (main) with values from my secondary worksheet (update).

my main worksheet has these column names: EmpName, EmpID, EmpSupervisor, Emp Director.

and my secondary worksheet: EmpName, EmpID, New Sup, NewDir, Status.

if an entry in the 2nd worksheet has STATUS listed as "mismatch", it will automatically pass the "new sup" and/or "new dir" data with the corresponding EmpID and overwrite "empsupervisor" and/or "empdirector" in the primary sheet.

something like this, i just can't put it in a correct syntax that vba can understand.

```
 for each STATUS = Mismatch in worksheet2

 update worksheet1.column("Empsupervisor") with worksheet2.column("New Sup").value

 where worksheet1.column("EmpID") = worksheet2.column("EmpID")

 next
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This method loops through all rows, checks for mismatch, finds the employee ID row, then moves the new supervisor and new director into the first sheet:

```
Sub TestIt()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, DestRow As Long, DestLast As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Name of main worksheet")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Name of secondary worksheet")

LastRow = ws2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
DestLast = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow 'Assumes first row has headers
    If ws2.Range("E" & CurRow) = "mismatch" Then 'Assumes mismatch is in column E
        If Not ws1.Range("B2:B" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            DestRow = ws1.Range("B2:B" & DestLast).Find(ws2.Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        End If
        ws1.Range("C" & DestRow).Value = ws2.Range("C" & CurRow).Value 'assumes supervisor is in column C in both sheets
        ws1.Range("D" & DestRow).Value = ws2.Range("D" & CurRow).Value 'assumes director is in column D in both sheets
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Explanation of `LastRow`:

> `Range("B" & Rows.Count)` goes to the last row on the sheet which is Row 1,048,576 in Excel '07, '10, and '13.  So imagine `Range("B1048576")`.  Then it performs `End(xlUp)` which is *"Equivalent to pressing END+UP ARROW"* according to MSDN.  This will go to the first cell in column B that is non-blank above B1048576.  The last command `.Row` returns that row number of the cell.

Explanation of `DestRow`:

> We are using a `Range.Find()` method to identify if the employeeID exists in the first worksheet and on what row it exists.  `Range.Find()` returns a range which is why I use `Range.Find().Row` because when found, we want to know the row we are going to.  However, if `Find()` doesn't find anything, it returns `Nothing` and `Nothing.Row` would error.  Therefore I do a quick `If Not Find() Nothing` to make sure the value is found.

Comment: hi chris can you explain what lastrow and destlast do? i find it a bit confusing on how it works.

Comment: thanks for the quick update, uhm another question, the if not statement there, uhm can you break it down too? thanks

Comment: ok i've spent an hour trying to break it down further on what that if not does. so can you explain what it does further? i can see that it's comparing B columns on both sheets but why is it counting at the end? (.row)?